# How to find the general solution to this linear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''-\frac{2y}{x^2} = 2x$$

I do not know how to solve this equation as there is $x^2$ on the left hand side. should I take $\frac{2}{x^2}$ as one of variable?

Comment: Do you know how to use the integrating factor?

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

To begin with, notice that

\begin{align*}
x^{2}y^{\prime\prime} - 2y = 2x^{3} \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2}y^{\prime\prime} + 2xy^{\prime}) - (2xy^{\prime} + 2y) = 2x^{3} \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2}y^{\prime})^{\prime} - (2xy)^{\prime} = 2x^{3}
\end{align*}

Then integrate both sides. Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

After multiplying with $x^2$, the homogeneous equation is of Euler-Cauchy type. The basis solutions of the form $x^r$ have to satisfy $0=r(r-1)-2=(r-2)(r+1)$. Then use the method of undetermined coefficients or variation of constants to find a particular solution.